# Getting an error creating a .net web service: Could not create type 'xxxxxxxxxx'

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

Trying to deploy a simple web service to access a mssql database and return JSON to Android (kotlin).  the URL is:  http://www.dfwcraftbeer.com/dbconnect/accessDatabase.asmx

I don't have access to IIS so I just used Visual studio '13 to deploy it to a folder on the root directory but I get the 'could not create type' error.

Yes, I do have accessDatabase.cs in the App_Code directory and the class is called accessDatabase.  WHen deployed on my local machine, it works just fine.

Here's the cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Collections.Generic;

//conn

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class accessDatabase : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private static String conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
    DataTable dt;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader reader;

    public accessDatabase()
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void addNewuser()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
        String resultJSON = "";
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        try
        {
            Context.Response.Clear();
            Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from ccusers", con);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            con.Close();

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<String, Object>> tableRows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<String, Object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col].ToString());
                }
                tableRows.Add(row);
            }
            resultJSON = serializer.Serialize(tableRows).ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resultJSON = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        Context.Response.Write(resultJSON);
        // return resultJSON;
    }


    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void verifyUser(string username, string userpassword)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
        String resultJSON = "";
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        try
        {
            Context.Response.Clear();
            Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from ccusers WHERE userName ='" + username + "' and userPW='" + userpassword + "';", con);
            Console.Write(cmd);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            con.Close();

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<String, Object>> tableRows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<String, Object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col].ToString());
                }
                tableRows.Add(row);
            }
            resultJSON = serializer.Serialize(tableRows).ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resultJSON = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        Context.Response.Write(resultJSON);
        // return resultJSON;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question but be careful, your code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection due to careless string concatenation in a SQL statement.

Comment: Yes, it is.  I knew that and this is just a test database.  I will make sure to use regex or something similar to prevent sql injection.

Comment: The only way to **really** avoid SQL injection is to use **parametrized queries** - _regex or something_ will **NOT** do

Comment: Gotcha.  I will research that.  Any ideas on my issue?

Comment: Here's my .asmx file: `<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/accessDatabase.cs" Class="accessDatabase" %>` IS there something wrong here?

Comment: Just FYI, this is being deployed on a VPS. I don't have access to IIS.  Not sure if that matters or not.